# Java, maven, hibernate - mapping issue

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, mapping

I am trying for more than an hour to find error and still I cant:

```
     cd C:\Users\zimnyk\Documents\NetBeansProjects\kwestionariusz; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_40" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.kwestionariusz.main\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_40\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
    Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
    Scanning for projects...

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Building kwestionariusz 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ kwestionariusz ---
    kwi 16, 2015 11:29:46 AM    org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager    <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
    kwi 16, 2015 11:29:46 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
    kwi 16, 2015 11:29:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
   16, 2015 11:29:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider

    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    kwi 16, 2015 11:29:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
    INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    kwi 16, 2015 11:29:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
    INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    kwi 16, 2015 11:29:46 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
    WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
    kwi 16, 2015 11:29:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
    INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Osoba.hbm.xml
    kwi 16, 2015 11:29:46 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
    WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
    Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.mycompany.kwestionariusz.util.NewHibernateUtil.<clinit>(NewHibernateUtil.java:31)
        at com.mycompany.kwestionariusz.main.main(main.java:20)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.legacyReadMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:375)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:304)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:516)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:512)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:686)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:769)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource(AnnotationConfiguration.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2255)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2227)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2207)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:213)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:201)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:177)
        at com.mycompany.kwestionariusz.util.NewHibernateUtil.<clinit>(NewHibernateUtil.java:27)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 13 of document  : The value of attribute "column" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character. Nested exception: The value of attribute "column" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.legacyReadMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:325)
        ... 22 more
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BUILD FAILURE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time: 2.478s
    Finished at: Thu Apr 16 11:29:47 CEST 2015
    Final Memory: 8M/106M
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project kwestionariusz: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

    To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

    For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException]
```

This is how error looks like, my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.mycompany.kwestionariusz.Osoba" table="DaneOsobowe">
        <property name="imie" column="Imie"/>
        <property name="nazwisko" column="Nazwisko"/>
        <property name="telefon" column="Telefon"/>
        <property name="email" column="Email"/>
        <property name="uczelnia" column="Uczelnia"/>
        <property name="doswiadczenie" column="Doswiadczenie"/>
        <property name="zainteresowania" column="Zainteresowania"/>
        <property name="skadSlyszal" column="SkadSlyszal"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
<mapping resource="Osoba.hbm.xml"/>


 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my first time with maven and with hibernate so also the error looks bad for me, could you help me please?

line 20 of main file is:

```
Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
```

and line ~31 of NewJavaUtil is:

```
}
     catch (Throwable ex) {
                // Log the exception. 
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
```

Comment: Rather than using println() I would really use ex.printStackTrace() to possibly get more information about the exception. And please don't use ExceptionInInitializerError, that error has a very specific meaning and this is not it (that you can lookup in the javadocs)

Comment: I added 
<id name="id" column="id" type="int" /> 
to mapping file to line 5, it helped with one error but new one is:
 ... 1 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 5 of document  : The value of attribute "table" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character. Nested exception: The value of attribute "table" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in new lines, when I added new line between everything in mapping file then it started to work

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was another change you did at the same time. Adding newlines in an XML file is not going to make any kind of difference.

Comment: I just deleted the whole thing and copied-pasted it again line by line

Comment: but still I had to add this:
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
to make reading works